# PHP - Echo an array data to form_input

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How to echo an array to a form?

My array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => item1
            [price] => 300
            [quantity] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => item2
            [price] => 400
            [quantity] => 2
        )
)
```

I tried like (codeigniter):

```
echo form_textarea('detail_prod',print_r($detail));
```

And I got like

[image]

what happen? why the result is 1 ?

It's possible to echo to a form in array format?

Comment: You have to run through the array with a foreach loop to echo things out. Which part of the form are you trying to populate? Textarea, textfield, select?

Comment: Did you check the function parameters of `form_textarea` ?

Comment: @SankarV : Ya beat me to it! :-) +1 to you. :-)  Try : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html.

Comment: what are you trying to do anyway? you want that exact pre formatted look inside a text area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the 2nd parameter `true` like below:

```
echo form_textarea('detail_prod',print_r($detail, true));
```

For your help:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Hope this will useful.